# Stop unity from being used in VNC sessions

Tags: unity, vnc

If I do not want the unity launcher to be used in VNC sessions (:2, :3, :4, etc.) is there a way to force all my VNC sessions to be gnome classic? I log into my system (12.04) using the "gnome classic" display, after installing gnome3 that is. Unity keeps crashing in my other VNC sessions.

Answer (score 1):

VNC show exactly the same what is currently on your desktop, so if you login to Gnome, VNC also will be with Gnome. If you are logged in Unity, you can only login as another user to different GUI (eg. Gnome) and connect via VNC to this another user desktop.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm seeing, I'm looking at it right now. My server is logged into to gnome (classic, no effects). When I connect to it with VNC using system_name:1 it's gnome. When I open a second VNC connection, e.g. system_name:2, it's the unity shell.